# what is this error in android programming?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose, build.gradle

hi what is this errors

I was developing navigation screen in jetpack compose which gave this error

```
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.optionals.OptionalsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

and my build.gradle: app file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'info.mm_seo.kotlinlearn'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.mm_seo.kotlinlearn"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.2.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.5"
}
```

and my build.gradle: project

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "KotlinLearn"
include ':app'
```

what is this error {
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
}

this is my navigation file

```
@Composable
fun Navigation() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screen.MainScreen.route) {
        composable(route = Screen.MainScreen.route) {
            MainScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(
            route = Screen.SecondScreen.route + "{name}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("name") {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                    defaultValue = "Sammy"
                    nullable = true
                }
            )
        ) { it ->
            SecondScreen(name = it.arguments?.getString("name"))
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainScreen(navController: NavController) {
    var text by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 50.dp)
    ) {
        TextField(
            value = text,
            onValueChange = {
                text = it
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
        Button(
            onClick = {
                navController.navigate(Screen.SecondScreen.withArgs(text))
            },
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.End)
        ) {
            Text(text = "To Second Screen")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SecondScreen(name: String?) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(text = "Hello $name")
    }
}
```

and this is my Screen class

```
sealed class Screen(val route: String) {
    object MainScreen: Screen("main_screen")
    object SecondScreen: Screen("second_screen")

    fun withArgs(vararg args: String): String {
        return buildString {
            append(route)
            args.forEach {  arg ->
                append("/$arg")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the kotlin version in your project?

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're encountering indicates that there are duplicate classes found in different modules of Kotlin standard library versions. This typically happens when there's a mix of different versions of Kotlin dependencies in your project.

Also I don't see the compose_ui_version variable defined in your script.